# How to make a request to a server when the iOS 9 app is closed?

Tags: ios, cordova, mobile

Good day. I've been reading a lot about this problem and there are many SO questions for previous versions of iOS.

I'm wondering, for iOS 9, Can I somehow send data to the server (a request with about 20-30kbs of payload data) if the app is not opened (So it wasn't started or was force-quit)?

Or is this still a no-go as of iOS 9.3?

I can go without even receiving the response from the server (i'm that desperate)

Comment: this might be a helpful read: https://blog.newrelic.com/2016/01/13/ios9-background-execution/

Comment: Thank yoiu, but I'm looking to send a request after force-quit. So background execution is not something that would work for this use-case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have been fighting with similar requirements for a long time. But we finally decided not to do it.

Apple suggests to do only a quick state log of your app so you can restore the same state when you open the app again. The best thing to do when the app is about to go to background is, to write something on disk which might be useful when the app loads again.

We tried connecting to the server every time user takes the app to background, but we saw a lot of app crash issues after adding this code. Coz, the OS force quits the app if its taking time to goto background.

We finally decided to store whatever info on the disk and then send it to server next time the app is open.

Comment: Thank you! But all I needed is to just send a request with a payload to the server. So there's absolutely no way of doing this properly?

Comment: Its a bad idea to connect to server when the app is about to go to background. You'll definitely end up crashing the app for most of the people on 3G.

Comment: In our case, we were sending only few bytes of data and faced crash for 20% of our users.

Comment: You could try to write the info to disk, and then try to perform the server call, this will save the state so it is retrievable, but if the connection is fast enough, the server call could go through before the app is force-quit.

Comment: @codetiger thank you. This is something I do not want )

Comment: @vrwim yup. I will do it, but I am looking for something that will send the data after force-quit. Like a way to create a request before the app is closed, so that this request is sent when the device is connected to the internet

Comment: @vrwim When you try to connect to the server, and the connection takes more than x seconds, (where x is time within which app should finish the function) or iOS will force crash the app.